# Evaluation error: Evaluation error: invalid 'tz' value

Tags: r

I am getting tz error and I tried few options available in this site but still not working. Can you please help.

Details below.

```
library(dplyr)

data(tidyverse_cran_downloads)
# Basic Usage
tidyverse_cran_downloads %>%
  + time_decompose(count, method = "stl")
```

Getting below error.

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Evaluation error: invalid 'tz' value..
```

Comment: is your data from package `anomalize`? then please add `library(anomalize)`to the code

Comment: I get a different error: `Error: Error time_decompose(): Object is not of class `tbl_df` or `tbl_time`.` (with the data set from `anomalize` package)

Comment: I tried adding library(anomalize)but same error.

Comment: I didn't suggest that adding this would solve your problem. This might help others find the data you're talking about - there is a data set called `tidyverse_cran_downloads` in the package anomalize. Is that the one you're using? Nobody can answer your question without the sample data.

Comment: It looks like your problem is from an example given in `anomalize::time_decompose`. Given that you got an error and I got a totally different error, this looks like a bug in the package `anomalize`. (The example in the help file does not work -- but it should.) So you might want to contact the package authors.

Comment: Finally I reinstall R and its working fine now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, only that you should remove the `+` after `%>%`. The code below works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(anomalize)

data(tidyverse_cran_downloads)
# Basic Usage
tidyverse_cran_downloads %>% time_decompose(count, method = "stl")
```